# Why my bottomSheet comes from the top of screen in the jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I have a bottomSheet but it comes from the top of the screen to the bottom when the screen is showing. How can I fix it?

**This is my bottomSheet codes:**

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun BottomSheet(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    buttonText: String,
    composable: @Composable () -> Unit,
    scope: CoroutineScope
) {
    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Expanded)
    )
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .padding(8.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
              
                Button(colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    backgroundColor = AppColor.brandColor.BLUE_DE_FRANCE,
                    contentColor = AppColor.neutralColor.DOCTOR
                ),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        small
                    ),
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                        }
                    }) {
                }
            }
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topEnd = medium, topStart = medium)
    ) {
        composable()
    }

}
```

the composable function is a google map screen

Comment: This is probably an error. If you replace `composable()` with something simple like `Text()`, does the problem still occur? On what devices did you reproduce it? Emulators, real devices?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov When I changed composable() to Text(), it's happened again. I have a real device

Comment: Your code works fine both on my emulator and on the real device. Try it out on the emulator.

Comment: @SaeedNoshadi I'm experiencing the same behavior, did you figure it out?

Comment: @SaraTalaat This approach is not correct. You should use a bottomsheet and the MainActivity and call the bottomsheet in the each page. Use this library:                    https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-material/

Answer (score 0):

My issue with this is only in the preview. When running it interactively or in the emulator it works fine. Maybe try this if you haven't already.